# Proof of weyl inequality

Tags: matrices

I am studying for the proof of Weyl inequlity from [a course note](http://www.ee.cuhk.edu.hk/~wkma/engg5781/new_notes/lecture%204-%20PSD-%20note.pdf): 1.3 Implications of the Courant-Fischer Theorem. It says that we can prove (d) from (c), that is we can prove: $\lambda_{j+k-1}(A+B)\leq\lambda_j(A)+\lambda_k(B)$ by using: $\lambda_k(A+B)\leq\lambda_{k-r}(A)$. I don't know how to prove it.

I have searched for some materials which may be useful, such as Corollary 2.6 from [this paper](https://arxiv.org/pdf/1910.01966.pdf). However, it involves "positive inertia index" which I don't know and can not understand the proof.

I know [Proof or reference to the Weyl inequalities?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2783345/proof-or-reference-to-the-weyl-inequalities) here has provided a blog link to one proof. But the course note has provided a different ways of proof and I really want to solve it out. Thank you.